# Does xtify support Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)?

Tags: ios, push-notification, push, urbanairship.com, xtify

I need to implement the push notifications for one of my projects. So I'm looking for third party solutions, I ended up with two of them : 
1- Urban Airship.
2- Xtify.

I did some research into the matter and found out that Urban Airship doesn't support ARC!.

 My question is : Does Xtify support ARC unlike Urban Airship?

Creat my own APNS is not of my options with my strict deadline.

best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would download the Xtify SDK you can see that it is a precompiled framework. Therefore no source code is provided and you don't have to worry if ARC is supported or not. It's already compiled.

You can choose if you want to use ARC in your own project or not.

Comment: Interesting !! Thank you Robin, for your quick response.